# What does this APL code do?

Tags: apl, dyalog

I am trying to learn APL. Following code snippet is from http://archive.vector.org.uk/art10011550 where it is stated that this code is as simple as reading 'MUMMY' in English!

```
R←((V⍳V)=⍳⍴V)/V
```

I have tried to check from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_syntax_and_symbols and I find that

```
R is outcome variable
← means gets a value
⍴ means number of components in each dimension of V
⍳ means vector of initial elements
```

Hence, this code processes input variable V and produces output variable R. However, I am not able to make out what this code exactly means or does? Could someone please explain it here. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code is equivalent to `R←∪V` - get the unique elements, leaving only the 1st of each item in the vector.

`V⍳V` gets, for each element in the vector V, the first index of that item in the same vector. So, for elements appearing the first time that's gonna be equal to the index of it in the vector. For `V←1 2 2 4 2 5` the result is `1 2 2 4 2 6`

`⍳⍴V` returns a range of numbers 1..length(V). For the same V as above, the result is `1 2 3 4 5 6`.

And the `=` checks for element-wise equality between the two - it finds, for each element, whether it's appeared in the vector before. For my example, this returns `1 1 0 1 0 1`.

And then the `/V` filters the initial vector, leaving only the items which have a `1` corresponding to them in the vector above. It results to `1 2 4 5`.

I'd read that expression as `Items of the vector V where the first appearance of the item equals it's index`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/8PBGGP2iYYKhgBoQkQm3KFcYU96t0cxgUkHvVuCePSAHM1beF8NAFNfaDajlVhXAA)

Comment: Pls. note that the ∪-function may not be available in some APLs. I remember it wasn't when I got into APL. But I also can't remember when it was introduced.

Comment: @MBaas the question is tagged [tag:dyalog], so I assumed it exists (though I don't know how long it's been in Dyalog APL)

Comment: It has always bothered me that this idiom is called "Unique". To my mind it returns *distinct* values, not unique. Unique means "occurs exactly once" (1 4 5 in the example above). I use the following for Uniqueness: V~((V⍳V)≠⍳⍴V)/V

Comment: @mappo For example, the unique elements of `1 4 4 5 3` in order of first appearance are `1 4 5 3`. Think of it more like "unique when first appeared".

Answer (score 4):

Searching for `((V⍳V)=⍳⍴V)/V` on [miserver.dyalog.com/Examples/Applications/Idiom_Search](http://miserver.dyalog.com/Examples/Applications/Idiom_Search.mipage) will give you: *Unique. Drop duplicates from vector.* Although you may not always be *that* lucky, as variable names may differ. You could also try searching there for a significant part without names, e.g. `)=⍳⍴` in this case.

The author of the article in question has written much expanded version, namely the excellent book [Mastering Dyalog APL](http://www.dyalog.com/mastering-dyalog-apl.htm). I can highly recommend it.